# replacing ubuntu 10.04 with lubuntu 13.04

Tags: lubuntu

I'm having some issues with upgrading 10.04 with lubuntu 13.04.  After having supposedly replaced 10.04, I find on startup that 10.04 opens up instead of lubuntu.  I have to restart a few times until lubuntu opens.  I need help in making lubuntu permanent.  Thanks

Comment: Hi, are you trying to upgrade? Upgrade has a special meaning in the context of Ubuntu because you can only upgrade to the next immediate version. You can't skip intermediate versions nor can you (IIRC) switch from one flavor to another as part of the upgrade. If you're on the LTS, you can upgrade from one LTS to the immediate next. For anything else, you need to do a clean install (after backing up your personal data).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a corrupt startup. As you are trying to install from scratch, I suggest completly formatting the hard drive from the `lubuntu live CD` and to then install lubuntu.